# SetState is not getting updated in parent component on submit button click. Sends method as prop to child which validates the input control in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I have created class components - a family component which is a parent component and Profile as child component.

I used to send method to child as prop and onSubmit click, I calls this to validate the input controls in child component and sends false value as parameter to parent component prop method to stop because of error and in that I updates IsValid property in State of Parent component as false.

But this state is not getting updated.
I have also bind the methods in parent component.

```
    IsValidFamilyMember = (IsValidFamily) => {        // IsValidFamily returns false from child
    this.setState({IsValidFamily1: IsValidFamily });    // IsValidFamily1 should set to false
  }



  

class Profile extends Form {
state: {IsValidFamily1: true}
}


doSubmit = async () => {

    var isFamilyValid = true;
    isFamilyValid = this.family.current != null ? this.validateFamily() : true;
}

validateFamily() {

    this.family.current.setErrorInState(this.state.data.FamilyDetail); //This will call child(Family component Method)
}

    //Child class Family
    
    class Family extends Form {
    
    setErrorInState = (data) => {
    //some Logic
    this.setIsValidFamily(false, errors);  // false is what I will return
    }
    }
    
    setIsValidFamily = async(IsValidFamily, errors) => {
        
    this.props.IsValidFamily(IsValidFamily);  // will call a parent method
      }
    
    //below is the parent method which will be call just after above method
    IsValidFamilyMember = async(IsValidFamily) => {    //IsValidFamily is returning false from child method
        
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, IsValidFamily1: IsValidFamily }));    // This is not updating state in Parent Component(profile component)
        
      }
```

But IsValidFamily1 which is initially declared as true is not updated to false
State is not getting updated

Comment: You're going to need to include more code.

Comment: business logic should be handled in the parent component, not the children

Comment: @BrianThompson, I have added more code for easy explanation! 
I am passing method as a prop to child component and passing value as false or true from child to parent component. So using setState in parent component to update the value comes from child component and that state is not getting updated.

Comment: @Kornelius, you are right but this is already coded project and I just have to correct validation in it and thats written in child method. validation of child components is getting managed in child method

Comment: @BrianThompson, I have understood that Using setState is a real headache because this will increase the code efforts and code becomes a mess. So moving towards hooks with Redux Toolkit!

Comment: @HarshilGandhi using redux will not simplify your code. It's just a (slightly) different pattern for managing state. Using state and setState is not a headache if you spend some time upfront learning it. State is a very fundamental part of React, and you won't realize it's full benefits without it. Redux is great for certain situations, but you will find the same problems there.